# Nginx fails randomly on big file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I got a Rails app stored at DigitalOcean. My Nginx is failing from time to time (lets say once in a 3) during the big file uploads (~70Mb). Also I have background Import process running (but I am not sure if it is relative to the issue).

I get 502 error and in the logs I see `upstream permanently closed connection while reading response header from upstream`.

My `nginx.conf` looks similar to this:

```
upstream backend {
  server unix://var/www/my_app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  root /var/www/my_app/current/public;

  client_max_body_size 600m;
  proxy_connect_timeout 1200s;
  proxy_send_timeout 1200s;
  proxy_read_timeout 1200s;

  client_header_timeout 1200s;
  client_body_timeout   1200s;
  client_header_buffer_size 1024k;
  client_body_buffer_size 600m;

  send_timeout 1200s;

  keepalive_timeout 1200s;

  large_client_header_buffers 8 1024k;

  fastcgi_read_timeout 1200s;

  error_log /var/www/my_app/current/log/nginx.error.log info;
}


http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 1200s;
  types_hash_max_size 2048k;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Could anyone please suggest what can be the reason of Nginx failing all the time and how it could be fixed?

Comment: The error message clearly states that it's an upstream problem. Your Rail app closes connection before sending full response.

Answer (score 0):

File uploads generally should not be performed during a request because you can never guarantee that the file will finish uploading before the request times out. You should use [Active Job](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) to upload the file in the background, then alert the user once the file is uploaded.

Comment: nginx handles uploads well, it doesn't pass request to the application until upload completes